# Shell Script Unable to send execution time via email

Tags: command-line, email, scripts, sendmail

I wrote a shell script which calculates the execution time of itself but the problem I'm facing is its not able to send the time difference via email. Please Help.

Here is the Script

```
#!/bin/bash

start=$(date +%s.%N)

ls /etc > /tmp/x

rm /tmp/x

executiontime(){
end=$(date +%s.%N)
diff=$(echo "$end-$start" | bc)
echo "Inside function $diff"
}

#Email Function
Sender="Sendmail"
Recpt="tarun@example.com"
Sub="Test"
Message="sendmail function $diff"

#Sendmail Function
sendmailfun() {
sendmail -F $Sender -it <<END_MESSAGE
To: $Recpt
Subject: $Sub

$Message
END_MESSAGE
}

executiontime
echo "outside function $diff"
sendmailfun
```

When I run this script the output on the cmd line is like follows

```
root@itpl-lptp-008:/home/incaendo/Downloads# sh executiontest.sh 
Inside function .008025182
outside function .008025182
```

But the email I get after executing the above script just have the line as follows

`sendmail function`
i.e. without the $diff value. why so? Is there anyway I can send the time difference via email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
Message="sendmail function $diff"
```

evaluates once when the script is executed. Then `diff` is `""`, so `Message` is `sendmail function`. The statement is not reexecuted after you set `diff` to a new value, so `sendmail function` is what gets emailed.

Wouldn't it be simpler to just run

```
time myscript.sh | mail -s "Test" tarun@example.com
```